# Qooxdoo How to get standard JavaScript SelectBox

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, touch, qooxdoo

is there a possibility to get in Qooxdoo the standard JavaScript SelectBox or is there a way to make the Qooxdoo SelectBox touch-friendly?

Qooxdoo Version is 3.5. and i make a Qooxdoo desktop application for PCs and Tablets.

Would be grateful for feedback & help! (And excuse my poor english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to qooxdoo 4.0 which added touch support to the desktop ui. This should also solve another set of problems like drag & drop or scrolling issues in the 3.5 release running on tables.